# How to Create and Destroy TGrid at Runtime in Firemonkey — Android and iOS App Dev

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tcomponent

I have a TGrid created at runtime. The procedure requires that I should destroy TGrid before I can re-create at "add item and refresh" button click. I noticed that if I don't destroy TGrid before re-creating it, heavy overheads cause to freeze my App on over 8 or more times of doing it.

I tried the following codes but no avail:

```
procedure TformMain.AddItemRefreshClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  TGrid1 : TTGrid;
begin
  if Assigned(TGrid1) then
  begin
    TGrid1.DisposeOf;
    {TGrid1.Free;    Tried this also but not working}
    {TGrid1 := nil;  Tried this also but not working}
  end;

  TGrid1 := TTGrid.Create(formMain);
  With TGrid1 do
  begin
    Parent := formMain;
    Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
    Margins.Top := 5;
    Margins.Left := 5;
    Margins.Right := 5;
    Margins.Bottom := 5;
    ScrollBars.Visible := True;
    Header.Format.Font.Size := 11;
    Cells.Format.Font.Size := 11;
    TabOrder := 0;
  end;
end;
```

I am getting Access Violation at Address... Sounds heave error!

Is there a simpler way that I can create and destroy visual component like TGrid at runtime?

Comment: Thank you for reminding (updated). I did your suggestion, see below, but I get the same Access Violation..

if Assigned(CanvassGrid) then
    begin
      FreeAndNil(CanvassGrid);
    end;

Comment: You must use a global variable to store the grid, so that its address is preserved between invocations of this method. That's the problem. (Currently, `TGrid1` (a very strange name of an object instance variable since it starts with `T`!) is a local variable of an unmanaged type, so it is uninitialized at the beginning of the method. Hence, it is a random pointer!) And then you should do `MyGrid.Free`, or -- even better -- `FreeAndNil(MyGrid)`. No need for `if Assigned(...)`, because `Free` does that check itself.

Comment: Perfect! I used global variable, removed if assigned and now it works! Please post your answer and will mark it as answered. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a non-local variable to store the grid, so that its address is preserved between invocations of this method.

Currently, `TGrid1` is a local variable. That essentially means that it is a variable that is created each time the routine is called. Its value isn't saved between invocations. And in Delphi, local variables of unmanaged types are not initialised, so that this is basically a random pointer. It is very dangerous to work with it! (And `Assigned` won't help you, since a random pointer might well be non-zero because it is ... well, random.)

(As an aside, the variable name `TGrid1` is very confusing, since it starts with `T`. Usually only type names start with `T`.)

So instead add a private field to your form class:

```
  private
    FMyGrid: TGrid;
```

(I don't know that the class name is: in your Q, you write both `TTeeGrid` and `TTGrid`.)

Then you can do

```
procedure TformMain.AddItemRefreshClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  // Free old grid
  FreeAndNil(FMyGrid);

  // Create new grid
  FMyGrid := TGrid.Create(formMain);
  with FMyGrid do
  begin
    Parent := formMain;
    Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
    Margins.Top := 5;
    Margins.Left := 5;
    Margins.Right := 5;
    Margins.Bottom := 5;
    ScrollBars.Visible := True;
    Header.Format.Font.Size := 11;
    Cells.Format.Font.Size := 11;
    TabOrder := 0;
  end;

end;
```

`FreeAndNil(FMyGrid)` basically does `FMyGrid.Free` and also sets the pointer to `nil` so that you won't end up with a dangling pointer in case the `TGrid.Create` constructor should raise an exception.

Furthermore, there is no need for the `if Assigned(FMyGrid) then` part, because `FMyGrid.Free` does that check.

Also notice that `FMyGrid` now is a member of a class, and as such it is initialised to `nil` from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry about confusions but already updated my question. Actually, I am using TeeGrid but I made it simpler TGrid here but it is the same. In less than 15 minutes this case is solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RickyBelmont: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: One last thing. I just tried running it in iOSSimulator but after 8 clicks it freeze a while like 2-3 minutes or longer with more clicks, the same issue. Does this solution work straight with iOS and Android?

Comment: @RickyBelmont: I don't know iOS and Android, but most likely that issue is unrelated to the code discussed in this Q and A. Hence, we cannot help you without seeing your other code.

Comment: You are right I might have to check again my query. It seems I need to limit the number of columns to be created at runtime because there is indeterminate number of columns created per click of the button. I have to limit it 10 columns only. This might solve my problem. Thank anyway.